# Exposed Firebase cloud messaging server key

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I uploaded my app into paly store I got an email from Google console says Leaked GCP FCM Server Keys

> Your app(s) expose FCM server keys.
>
> To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article.

I'm just new into this and I gave a deadline to fix it so what to do?

I did my research and I found that I need to Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 but I don't know how to do it in android studio

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging server key is used to authorize an app server to access Google services, including sending messages via deprecated legacy HTTP API. **It shouldn't be included anywhere in your client code.**

You may refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1) on how to migrate from FCM legacy HTTP API to FCM HTTP v1 API. Here is also a sample [quickstart project](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/tree/master/messaging) on how to send messages using Node.js.